# C# publish Winform application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, publish, cefsharp

I'm trying to publish an `Winform` application that i build with Visual Studio 2013 `.Net 4.5.2`.
After i publish it and send the install to another computer it's install but when i try to run it i get an error:

```
Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE983.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WERF20C.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WERF21D.tmp.mdmp

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I check this files:

```
WERE983.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml 
WERF20C.tmp.appcompat.txt
```

And this is what the contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="VAScanProducts.exe" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CefSharp.Core.dll" SIZE="1227264" CHECKSUM="0x96A9A86D" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x130D03" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="04/18/2017 05:44:15" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/18/2017 05:44:15" EXPORT_NAME="CefSharp.Core.dll" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CefSharp.dll" SIZE="185344" CHECKSUM="0xBE52941B" BIN_FILE_VERSION="57.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="57.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="57.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="CefSharp" COMPANY_NAME="The CefSharp Authors" PRODUCT_NAME="CefSharp" FILE_VERSION="57.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="CefSharp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="CefSharp.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2010-2017 The CefSharp Authors" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2E412" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="57.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="57.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="04/18/2017 05:43:55" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/18/2017 05:43:55" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="CefSharp.WinForms.dll" SIZE="23552" CHECKSUM="0xE50D82BF" BIN_FILE_VERSION="57.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="57.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="57.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="CefSharp.WinForm" COMPANY_NAME="The CefSharp Authors" PRODUCT_NAME="CefSharp" FILE_VERSION="57.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="CefSharp.WinForms.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="CefSharp.WinForms.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2010-2017 The CefSharp Authors" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x7B0E" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="57.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="57.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="04/18/2017 05:44:19" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/18/2017 05:44:19" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" SIZE="653824" CHECKSUM="0xABD0EDC9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="10.0.3.21018" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="10.0.3.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="10.0.3" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Json.NET" COMPANY_NAME="Newtonsoft" PRODUCT_NAME="Json.NET" FILE_VERSION="10.0.3.21018" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © James Newton-King 2008" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xA4DDC" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="10.0.3.21018" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="10.0.3.0" LINK_DATE="06/10/2061 13:14:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="06/10/2061 13:14:05" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="VAScanProducts.exe" SIZE="16384" CHECKSUM="0xDA25CD21" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="VAScanProducts" PRODUCT_NAME="VAScanProducts" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="VAScanProducts.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="VAScanProducts.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2018" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/01/2018 00:00:30" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/01/2018 00:00:30" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000feefe9ec5f02546ae654935471793c1b87db67f2" PROGRAM_ID="0000da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="KernelBase.dll" SIZE="275456" CHECKSUM="0xDD5DB326" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Kernelbase" INTERNAL_NAME="Kernelbase" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x4FD50" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" LINK_DATE="05/12/2017 18:06:06" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/12/2017 18:06:06" EXPORT_NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000ff428087a9ddf81b3edcb9f46e3b5ca798b97376" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="1114112" CHECKSUM="0x1725986C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x11A808" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.23807" LINK_DATE="05/12/2017 18:06:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/12/2017 18:06:05" EXPORT_NAME="KERNEL32.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00005daf7834295c8a8d2b58f1e3e780e39a6842a4c2" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<WERReportMetadata>
    <OSVersionInformation>
        <WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion>
        <Build>7601 Service Pack 1</Build>
        <Product>(0x30): Windows 7 Professional</Product>
        <Edition>Professional</Edition>
        <BuildString>7601.23807.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600</BuildString>
        <Revision>1130</Revision>
        <Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
        <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
        <LCID>1033</LCID>
    </OSVersionInformation>
    <ProblemSignatures>
        <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
        <Parameter0>VAScanProducts.exe</Parameter0>
        <Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>5a497a1e</Parameter2>
        <Parameter3>VAScanProducts</Parameter3>
        <Parameter4>1.0.0.0</Parameter4>
        <Parameter5>5a497a1e</Parameter5>
        <Parameter6>1</Parameter6>
        <Parameter7>17</Parameter7>
        <Parameter8>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</Parameter8>
    </ProblemSignatures>
    <DynamicSignatures>
        <Parameter1>6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>1033</Parameter2>
        <Parameter22>0a9e</Parameter22>
        <Parameter23>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter23>
        <Parameter24>0a9e</Parameter24>
        <Parameter25>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter25>
    </DynamicSignatures>
    <SystemInformation>
        <MID>B73736F6-D3D2-46FF-BDB0-6668893CF9EF</MID>
        <SystemManufacturer>VMware, Inc.</SystemManufacturer>
        <SystemProductName>VMware Virtual Platform</SystemProductName>
        <BIOSVersion>6.00</BIOSVersion>
    </SystemInformation>
</WERReportMetadata>
```

=========
Edit- First error message:
[image]

Any idea what can be the problem with the publish?

Comment: What is the actual error text in `event viewer`?

Comment: You seem to have posted only a partial error message, and only the un-helpful part of it. Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  just added the first error message